# How to sort the data in each sliding window?

Tags: pandas, dolphindb

There is a piece of code:

```py
d["p1"] = d["p"].rolling(5).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x).corr(pd.Series(sorted(x))))
```

Does dolphindb have a solution which is equivalent to the data processing method of this pandas code?
Only sort the data in each window, but not the data in the entire column.

Answer (score 0):

Use a user-defined function, refer to the following:

```py
select moving(x->corr(x, sort(x)), close, 5) from t context by code
```